# Delete after button is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form where when I delete some product is delete also the image from folder. So far so good. When I click on button `Delete` I get panel where is asking me to confirm or cancel. The problem is that the actual deletion is happen when I firstly click on `Delete` then it doesn't matter if I `confirm` or `cancel`. 
This is the delete.php file

```
<?php        
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$id = 0;    
if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}           
if ( isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `path` FROM cats where `id` = :id"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        unlink("" . $result[0]);
        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM cats WHERE id = :id"))
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }     
    Database::disconnect();
 }      
?>

<form role="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
  <p class="alert alert-error">Are you sure?
    <div class="form-actions">
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm</button>
       <a class="btn btn-info" href="main.php">Cancel</a>                      
    </div>
  </p>
</form>
```

This file `delete.php` is open after I click in `cats.php` button `delete`

Comment: The reason the product is always getting deleted is because the code at the top is always going to run.  You have to make it run only after the form has been submitted.

Comment: it would be good to keep the files of html and php separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['id'])) 
{
    //then delete
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace your code with the below one and you are done

```
<?php        
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['id']))//YOU NEED TO CHECK IF THE FORM HAS SUBMITTED 
{
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $id = 0;    
    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) 
    {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }           
    if ( isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `path` FROM cats where `id` = :id"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($result = $stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            unlink("" . $result[0]);
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM cats WHERE id = :id"))
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }     
        Database::disconnect();
     }
}          
?>
```

Check the form submission then perform delete always otherwise when the file loads the code will be executed without any validation.

Do not forget to accept answer if it help you :)